# Restrict a user to a specific seat?

Tags: xorg, multiseat

I have set up a two-user multi-seat arrangement with `loginctl`. Is it possible to restrict a user account to a specific seat? Ideally, GDM would only offer the respective account on each seat.

I am using Fedora 23.